# Voltage reference voltage drop

Tags: voltage-reference, voltage

I have two potentiometers and a single voltage reference, connecting them causes a few mV voltage drop in the simulator:

[image]

Adding an op amp solves the problem but then comes input offset voltage and temperature stability problems:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fm3Fyr.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

How do I properly use a single voltage reference for two potentiometers without getting voltage drop?

Comment: Why not use fixed R’s with a bandgap Vref , and quad OA because Zeners are pretty wide tolerance >5% and temperature sensitive.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 Can you please explain a little bit more? you mean I do that in the simulator to get a "voltage reference like" behavior? because on the PCB I don't have enough room to use a quad op amp...

Comment: The ratio of Load reg Err= source / load+source = Load regulation error. The Zener source has a lower incremental resistance dv/DI but not low enough. Whereas the OA reduces its Zout by AOL

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 I'm going to use [LM4040](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/LM4040-LM4040D.pdf) Vref, I'm not sure though is it going to behave like a Zener or not. what does "AOL" stands for?

Comment: Are you really going to have a switch in your circuit or will the pair of potentiometers always be connected? Which grade (A/B/C/D) of LM4040 were you planning on using?

Comment: @brhans The switch is there just to demonstrate the voltage drop. A grade.

Comment: Well, the LM4040A-2.048 has a max tolerance of +/-15mV, which is 2.5x greater than the variation caused by the pots... Considering that it'll be a constant, you can calibrate it out in the same way that you'd calibrate out the LM4040A's own inaccuracy. You could avoid it by compensating for the change in the LM4040A's operating current due to the pots being in parallel, but unless you're equally as concerned by the LM4040A's tolerance it's probably not worth the effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The accuracy of the LM4040 is guaranteed with a 100uA current and typically changes only 300uV for a current change from 75uA to 1mA. The guarantee is +/2mV at room temperature and +/-15mV over a wider span.

Self-heating will affect it too.

So if you use even a modest precision op-amp you won't affect the initial accuracy or drift much. The antediluvian OP-07 has guaranteed Vos of as low as 75uV (which is << 2~15mV) and a guaranteed drift of less than 1.3uV/°C compared to the +/-31uV **typical** drift of the best LM4040 at the optimum current.

There are much better op-amps available than the 1975-era OP-07 in 2020.

So, yes, buffering it if you expect large changes in load will help, and it will reduce self-heating drift and changes with source voltage even if the load is fairly fixed. You can also low-pass filter out some of the LM4040 noise, which is probably around 200-250uVp-p.

That will also allow you to operate it at an optimum current, with a large series resistor (perhaps from a relatively high voltage supply as in your example) so the current is closer to constant.

You should really add up **all** the sources of error and compare it to your target, to see what is necessary or desirable.